# DB2 SQL query result excess data

Tags: sql, db2

[image]

DB2 version 10 and 11
SQL is:

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT ID FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) T(ID)
GROUP BY ID) WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)
  )
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID IN(2,3)
UNION
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE 1 = 0
```

Expected results is 2 row 2 and 3, but there is 3 records

The original complex query has been simplified

Comment: Holy guacamole. That's a nasty bug in Db2 11.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "looks like" a bug, **changing from union to union all made no difference**, but if you reverse the order of selects in the final query you will get only 2 rows returned. Perhaps others can explain the difference. The following from a DB2 fiddle:

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT ID FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) T(ID)
GROUP BY ID) WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)
  )
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID IN(2,3)
--UNION
--SELECT ID FROM T WHERE 1 = 0
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT ID FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) T(ID)
GROUP BY ID) WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)
  )
--SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID IN(2,3)
--UNION
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE 1 = 0
```

no rows returned

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT ID FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) T(ID)
GROUP BY ID) WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)
  )
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID IN(2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE 1 = 0
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT ID FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) T(ID)
GROUP BY ID) WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)
  )
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE 1 = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID IN(2,3)
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YMBMHJMo)

Comment: This definitively looks like a DB2 bug, at least in LUW version 11.5, and it seems related to the management of the CTE. The query runs well when ran over a traditional table instead. See [Db2 bug fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/94Y78JZr).

Comment: Thanks. That confirms it as a bug in my mind.